# Multiple batch file definitions in a single .bat file

Tags: batch-file

Assume there are three .bat files - I have many more - and each of these only has a few lines of code in them.
Now I save these in a bat folder on my C: drive and added that to my PATH.
However, I don't want this folder to get cluttered.
What I want to do is combine multiple definitions in a single file.
Such that my commands still work e.g. opengaragedoor(.bat) but I don't have to define a new file for each.
I want something like this:

```
def opengaragedoor:
  //opengaragedoor.bat code
def turnonlights:
  //turnonlights.bat code
def ...
  // ....bat code
```

**Note: I don't want to run many bat files at once by typing a single command, I just want to define many in a single one but still be able to call them individually**

Comment: Please `edit` your question to include some examples of how you would wish to `call them individually`. Are you expecting to simply type `opengaragedoor` at the prompt and have the `opengaragedoor` section of `allmybatfiles.bat` executed or are you expecting to be able to include `call %opengaragedoor% opengaragedoorparameters` in your batchfiles?

Comment: @Magoo I stated in the NOTE that I want to run them by typing a single command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use labels in a helper batch file and a tiny bit of glue to make them act as subroutines.  For instance:

`utils.cmd`:

```
@echo off

goto %1

:open_garage_door
echo Opening the Garage Door
goto :EOF

:open_pod_bay_door
echo I'm afraid I can't do that
goto :EOF
```

And using it in `example.cmd`:

```
@echo off

echo In example, open the pod bay door:
call utils.cmd open_pod_bay_door
echo Back in example
```

Running `example.cmd` would output:

```
In example, open the pod bay door:
I'm afraid I can't do that
Back in example
```

Comment: This is sort of what i'm looking for. However, i'd be calling the files myself, thus having to type `util open_pod_bay_door`. This is only a minor inconvenience tho. I could simply name it `c.bat`